# Dropdown shows up on different combobox than what I'm typing in

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have three independent searchable comboboxes in a sheet with different ranges of data to be filled with.

1. I type and select correctly from the first. (Dropdown shows up as expected)
2. When I go to second combo and start to type, instead of showing possible data in its own dropdown, the first dropdown pops up again. (I reselect the only item now as there is only one item that matches the text entered in the first step)
   Then I can finish searching my second combobox. No dropdown, but I can select from correct item list.
3. When I go to the third, the second dropdown pops up, as described in 2nd step, I reselect the only item (as there is only one item that matches the text entered in the second step)
   After this I can add the content in the third dropdown.

I have a few more buttons, and each time I press one of them dropdowns appear randomly(from my point of view)
Sometimes Excel crashes with no error code.

```
Private Sub CMSearchProiecte_Change()
    CMSearchProiecte.ListFillRange = "CMSearchProiecteDropDown"
    Me.CMSearchProiecte.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub CMSearchEchip_Change()
    CMSearchEchip.ListFillRange = "CMSearchEchipDropDown"
    Me.CMSearchEchip.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub CMSearchFurnizor_Change()
    CMSearchFurnizor.ListFillRange = "CMSearchFurnizorDropDown"
    Me.CMSearchFurnizor.DropDown
End Sub

'3 more subs for 3 buttons
```

I saw other posts, videos, but they were about one combobox/sheet.
I tried to put them in separate modules, tried to call them - (they do the search, as they have filled already in the `ListFillRange` property from previous attempts
(*if i delete that property from the properties window, there are no results, ListFillRange doesn't get set to "CMSearch____DropDown" NameRange again*),
and dropdown doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

made it work with activate method!

```
Private Sub CMSearchFurnizor_Change()
If CMSearchFurnizor.Activate = True Then
CMSearchFurnizor.ListFillRange = "CMSearchFurnizorDropDown"
Me.CMSearchFurnizor.DropDown
End If
End Sub
```